# How to avoid using global variable to set text in GLViewWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqtgraph

I found this [Google groups discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/pyqtgraph/FNxcMh3M6nc/XGS2C447n_MJ) about how to display text in pyqtgraph's `GLViewWidget`. I want to be able to change the displayed text, so I modified the code like so:

```
import pyqtgraph.opengl as gl
from PyQt4.Qt import QApplication
class MyGLView(gl.GLViewWidget):
        def paintGL(self, *args, **kwds):
                global text
                gl.GLViewWidget.paintGL(self, *args, **kwds)
                self.renderText(0, 0, 0, text)
app = QApplication([])
w = MyGLView()
w.show()
text = "123"
w.renderText(0, 0, 0, text)
```

This is probably not the best way to do it. Is it possible to rewrite this code to avoid using the global variable `text`?

Comment: Why not just make `text` a property of `MyGLView` ?

Comment: @Luke I'm a python beginner, can you show an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `text` out of the global namespace, make it an attribute of the `MyGLView` class. Example:

```
import pyqtgraph.opengl as gl
from PyQt4.Qt import QApplication

class MyGLView(gl.GLViewWidget):
    def __init__(self, text):
        super(MyGLView, self).__init__()
        self.text = text

    def setText(self, text):
        self.text = text
        self.update()

    def paintGL(self, *args, **kwds):
        gl.GLViewWidget.paintGL(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.renderText(0, 0, 0, self.text)


app = QApplication([])
w = MyGLView(text="O HAI World")
w.show()
```

Comment: Thanks. You probably forgot to remove the line `global text` in the `paintGL` definition.

Comment: Unfortunately, I get an error: `File "/Users/sharix/PycharmProjects/simple/test.py", line 19, in <module> w.show()` `RuntimeError: super-class __init__() of type MyGLView was never called`.

Comment: Fixed by adding `super(MyGLView, self).__init__()` before `self.text = text` in `MyGLView` `__init__` definition. I can now set up the widget with `w = MyGLView(text="")` and then change the text with `w.text="test"`.

Comment: Right. This is what I get for posting untested code.